# Call function using subtype overload

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

Consider the following program

```
class A {};

class B : public A {};

void fun(A v) { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }

void fun(B v) { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }

void call(A v) { fun(v); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   A a;
   B b;

   call(a);
   call(b);
   fun(a);
   fun(b);
}
```

It will print

```
A
A
A
B
```

Is there a way for the program to notice that the variable is actually a `B` in the second case, and hence call the overloaded `fun(B)`, so that the output would become the following instead?

```
A
B
A
B
```

Comment: make `call` a template?

Comment: Function overloading is resolved at compile-time. Also, welcome to the world of object slicing. In `void call(A v) { fun(v); }`, `v` is **never** a `B`,

Comment: The variable is not actually a B in the second case, since you are calling by value, and not by reference/pointer. It's an A that is a sliced copy of the B you are passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

You could use a template for your `call` function.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};

class B : public A {};

void fun(A v) { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }

void fun(B v) { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
void call(T v) { fun(v); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   A a;
   B b;

   call(a);
   call(b);
   fun(a);
   fun(b);
}
```

This will only compile if there is an overload of `fun` that takes a parameter of type `T`, which in your case is `A` or `B`.

[Working example](http://cpp.sh/9mgl)

**Option 2**

Alternatively, you could make these free functions into `virtual` class methods and actually use polymorphism.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void fun() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
    void call() { fun(); }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void fun() override { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   A a;
   B b;

   a.call();
   b.call();
   a.fun();
   b.fun();
}
```

[Working example](http://cpp.sh/6n7q)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want `fun` to be part of the classes?  If `fun` was a `virtual` method on the class, and call took an `A` and simply did `v.fun()` it would find the proper implementation to execute